# Jena RDF file parsing issue

Tags: java, rdf, jena, arp

Am trying to parse a simple rdf file using InputStream. I will have a huge file to read, so I need to reading it from input stream.

My code :

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

        String file = "/Users/rdf_files/testRDF.rdf";

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);

        if (in == null) {
            System.out.println("file not found");
        }

        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        model.read(in, null);
        model.write(System.out);


        System.out.println("read the file");
    }
```

My file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:cd="http://www.recshop.fake/cd#">

<rdf:Description
rdf:about="http://www.recshop.fake/cd/Empire Burlesque">
  <cd:artist>test 1</cd:artist>
  <cd:country>USA</cd:country>
  <cd:company>Columbia</cd:company>
  <cd:price>10.90</cd:price>
  <cd:year>1985</cd:year>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description
rdf:about="http://www.recshop.fake/cd/Hide your heart">
  <cd:artist>test 2</cd:artist>
  <cd:country>UK</cd:country>
  <cd:company>CBS Records</cd:company>
  <cd:price>9.90</cd:price>
  <cd:year>1988</cd:year>
</rdf:Description>

</rdf:RDF>
```

I am getting exception like :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.icu.text.StringPrepParseException
```

Can anyone tell me what am doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like you have not set up the classpath correctly. Please check it.

Comment: "I will have a huge file to read, so I need to reading it from input stream." -- Untrue.  model.read(file name) will stream-read the file. It will however all end up in memory.  RDFDataMgr has stream processing operations - see StreamRDF.

Comment: Which version of Jena?  jena no longer uses ICU4j (which is where that class is, I guess)

Comment: Thanks Andy for your input, I could fix the above issue, do have any example of RDF streaming where we can read rdf blocks.

Answer (score 0):

slm, 
Ihad the same problem and i fixed it by adding "com.ibm.icu_3.4.4.1.jar" to my classPath i hope that this can help you :)